# GitHub branch syncing with the master for no obvious reason

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

I'm coding in Rstudio and my workflow is along these lines:

1. make a new branch using Rstudio's UI
2. add some code or fix a bug
3. commit code when I'm satisfied and push to GitHub
4. merge the new code into the master on GitHub
5. pull the latest master code from GitHub into Rstudio using it's UI
6. delete any local/remote branches via command line (because Rstudio doesn't have the functionality and doesn't sync with GitHub when it comes to remote branch deletion)

This might not be the most efficient way of doing things (I'm new to git) but it works well enough except for the problem I'm having. Twice now, seemingly at random, I've created a new branch, worked on it and when I've gone back to check something in the master they are identical. The code changes I've made in the branch have already synced with the master.

This is what the last two lines of the History look like:

[git history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw35h.png)

independant_erp_norm_regressions is the last branch I merged into the master while preprocess_select_global_pars is the current branch which is syncing to the master unduly.

I'm at a loss as to what is going on because I'm doing the same thing as I usually do and haven't been able to find any similar questions on stackoverflow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (as well as any ways in which I can streamline my workflow).

Comment: This could be a bug with your R studio Git plugin.  Do you have access to the command line Git bash?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the response, yes I do, is there any particular command I can use to check if the two versions are syncing with each other outside of Rstudio? I think git diff will look at only committed changes right?

Comment: No idea.  Just do the operations from the Bash and see if you get the same unexpected behavior.  For the record, I have definitiely worked with Git plugins which were rife with bugs.

Comment: You might be able to limit `git`'s access to your repo: if you have `ssh-agent` or some credentials-saving agent, then when you aren't intending to sync, disable the agent. For me, I use KeePass and KeeAgent, and one of its configuration options it to confirm every attempt to access the SSH keys. It might not tell you why it's happening, but at least you can know *when* it's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok thanks for the responses guys, as per Tim's reply I decided to commit the changes made to the new branch via Rstudio's UI and check in command line to see what happened behind the scenes. (After that I thought I would do an entire branch/merge via command line to see if the problem persisted or if it was a Rstudio bug). So just before committing the changes Rstudio's git interface showed that Master and my branch were still in sync up to and including having staged files selected together. After committing I used "git show-branch" in command line and it showed that only the correct branch had a new commit, this was mirrored in Rstudio's Git history interface and after merging via GitHub all is well. So it seems like it was just an Rstudio-git bug of sorts.